# how can I use flutter_phone_direct_caller packages for real

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-packages

I run below code but it's not working for real

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phone_direct_caller/flutter_phone_direct_caller.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _callNumber,
              child: Text('Call Number'),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

_callNumber() async {

  const number = '+82)010-7335-7424';
  print("hi"); //set the number here
  bool? res = await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(number);
}
```

[image]

how can i run for real???
Should I have to build apk and run in real phone..?

Answer (score 0):

I think for call dialer or Direct navigate to the dialer, the best package will be [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher). At first please install the package & then try the below code ---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child:  ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _callNumber,
              child: Text('Call Number'),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

_callNumber() async {

  const number = '+82)010-7335-7424';
  print("hi"); //set the number here
  if (!await launchUrl(Uri.parse("tel://$number"))) throw 'Could not launch ${Uri.parse("tel://$number")}';
}
```

Basically, I change the code inside the `_callnumber` method which is

```
_callNumber() async {

  const number = '+82)010-7335-7424';
  print("hi"); //set the number here
  if (!await launchUrl(Uri.parse("tel://$number"))) throw 'Could not launch ${Uri.parse("tel://$number")}';
}
```